# Plot Multiple boolean columns in X - axis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have a data frame (df3) with features like:
These are the details of customers who accepted the marketing campaigns. 1 means accepted and 0 means not accepted

```
Customer ID AcceptedCmp1 AcceptedCmp2 AcceptedCmp3 Income Kidhome
123             1            0            0        3456   1 
456             0            1            0        5678   0 
786             1            1            1        6555   1
987             0            0            0        5444   1
```

I want the output to be something like this showing the marketing campaigns with highest and lowest acceptance:

Thanks
[image]

Comment: please elaborate your problem. There is not much information in the question

Comment: kindly check the updated question...

Comment: Is there value counts in y axis?

Comment: Yes, either counts or percentage......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. Countplot of seaborn will count the values of columns and plot it, use pd.melt to plot columns. Here x="variable" and hue="value" came from melted(pd.melt(df3)) df3.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.countplot(x="variable", hue="value", data=pd.melt(df3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

zeros = [data[column].value_counts()[0] for column in data.columns]
ones = [data[column].value_counts()[1] for column in data.columns]
n = len(data.columns)
plt.bar(np.arange(n)-0.1, zeros, width=0.2, label='0')
plt.bar(np.arange(n)+0.1, ones, width=0.2, label='1')
plt.xticks(np.arange(n), data.columns)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: KeyError: 0.0..... I changed data to my data frame name but still this error..

Comment: There are other columns as well with values in 0 and 1 but I only want AcceptedCmp columns...

Comment: Define a new data frame with just columns you want to plot and run the same